# How to use Oracle Apex 5 Project Gantt?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I'm completely new with oracle apex just know the simple basics and I saw the option in the Chart that's Project Gantt, when I press the SQL query I always get the

" Wrong number of columns selected in the SQL query. See Help of attribute for details. "

so my answer is what kind of Table do I need to create in the database to make a simple project Gantt just for practice

REMEMBER I'm completely noob and new with this i just wanna practice my skills in here because there's not a lot of info on the web about this topic

I tried to run some simple tables on the database but I seem to add the wrong one, like what kind or what do I need to add on the table to make the project Gantt run

Comment: The error message suggests you read the Help of the attribute. To do this, click the Help tab.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to APEX and stack overflow. You picked a more complex type of chart - and that is quite picky as far a the query is concerned.

The APEX team maintains sample apps for a number of advanced functionalities. Those apps contain sample data and a lot of sample pages. To install those:

1. Go to apex.oracle.com/samples
2. Select "Sample Charts"
3. Download and install sample-charts.sql

There is a gantt chart page with several examples. Examine those to learn the details or use the source query as a starting point for a gantt chart in your application.